# Why does Erlang offer both `import` for modules and `include` for headers?

Tags: import, erlang, header-files

Erlang's `-import()` directive lets you import code from other modules. Its `include()` directive lets you import code from headers. Why reasons are there to prefer either one over the other?

My hunch is that headers are good for short, easy-on-the-compiler kinds of code, such as record definitions, when you don't want to have to qualify the

Learn You Some Erlang states[1] that "Erlang header files are pretty similar to their C counter-part: they're nothing but a snippet of code that gets added to the module as if it were written there in the first place." Thus inclusion seems to cause the compiler to duplicate effort across different modules. And header files are what appear to be an optional complication on top of the mandatory module system. So why would I ever use a header file?

[1] https://learnyousomeerlang.com/a-short-visit-to-common-data-structures

Answer (score 3):

Erlang's `-import` just allows you to call imported functions without the `Module`. It hurts legibility and should not be used: You need to check the import directive to know whether a function is local or external to the module.

With header files you get the same functionality as in `C`, you can use them to share `-record` definitions instead of having a dto-like module (1), you can use them to include `-define`s to use the same macros (2).

1:

```erlang
-record(position, {x, y}).
```

Imagine that you have `#position{}` throughout the code, instead of defining the record everywhere and updating all of the copies when the record definition changes, you use a header (or a dto module with opaque types, but that's for another question).
And let's just hope that you remember to update all the copies, otherwise chaos ensues.

2:

```erlang
-define(ENUM01, enum01).
-define(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, 1000).
```

Instead of using `enum01` and `1000` everywhere, which is error prone and requires multiple updates if you need to change them, you define them in a header and use them as `?ENUM01` and `?DEFAULT_TIMEOUT`

Or you can be more thorough when testing:

```erlang
-ifdef(TEST).
-define(assert(A), true = A).
-else
-define(assert(A), A).
-endif.
```

Or you can include some useful information:

```erlang
-define(LOG(Level, X), logger:log(Level, X, #{line => ?LINE}).
```

Answer (score -2):

The Erlang standard library uses header files to provide the ability to add metadata to your code.

For instance, EUnit functionality:

```
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").
```

Answer (score -4):

`import` is helpful in building encapsulations, whereas `include` is kind of pre-processing(which means code will be part of the unit before it gets through the compiler).

An `import` ensues a dependency between two modules, which means a module A importing module B *has* B as dependency ... Whereas an `include` is extensional which means a module has *included* some code and that code *is* part of the module itself, and that is what header files do.

`module`(s) and `header`(s) are 2 semantically different things and serve different purposes. With modules, we can build abstractions by using the `export`(s), keep things confined by not exporting them, import from other modules(but they are not exported by default), re-export imported things etc etc. So when we `import` stuff, we can call upon functions from the other module, but only those which are exported in the other module. However that is not the case with `header` files. Everything inside a `header` file becomes part of the module which includes them. There is no sense of export/import inside header files. And header files are quite useful for writing and distributing definition(s) which otherwise could lead to redundancy in case of large programs.

So essentially they are 2 different things, so 2 different keywords available at our disposal. So don't prefer one over the other. Learn both of them as we need both of them.

Comment: Please leave a comment if you think the answer is `not useful`.